# GitHub oauth in small window

Tags: github

Does GitHub have some get parameter to open this link in adaptibe mode or an another way without scrolls?

**Image here**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just zoom out. As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to do that without just zooming.